# How to parse XML effectively using spring batch in case of mutiple tags

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a XML file which i have to parse using spring batch but i am not sure how to parse the files in multiple batches.

A Sample of what my file looks like

```
<information>
    <college>
        <header info>
    </college>
    <student>
        <student 1 info>
    </student>
    <student>
        <student 2 info>
    </student>
    <student>
        <student 3 info>
    </student>
</information>
```

Sample student record

```
<student>
        <name>Tony Tester</name>
        <rollNo>1</rollNo>
        <enrollmentDate>2016-10-31</enrollmentDate>
        <sampleTimeStamp>2016-11-07T05:50:45</sampleTimeStamp>
        <salary>16.57</salary>
</student>
```

For my case there can be N number of records for student and the value of N can be really huge. My requirement is to parse the XML file and put the details of all the students into database and since i am using spring batch i don't want to load the whole XMl file at once. Due to large number of records i want to read the student data in batches let's say in a chunk size of 300. My Java POJO looks like

Information.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="information")
public class Information
{
      @XmlElement(name="college")
      private College college;

      @XStreamAlias("student")
      private List<Student> student;

      ... getter, setter and constructor
}
```

I am not sure whether my requirement is even feasible or not and if feasible how should i code for my itemReader in spring batch configuration. For now i tried to read only student data without and college tags and for that implemetation my reader looks like

ItemReader

```
 @StepScope
    @Bean(name="xmlReader")
    public SynchronizedItemStreamReader<StudentDTO> reader() 
    {
        StaxEventItemReader<StudentDTO> xmlFileReader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
        xmlFileReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("students.xml"));
        xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("student");

        Map<String, Class<?>> aliases = new HashMap<>();
        aliases.put("student", StudentDTO.class);

        StudentConverter converter = new StudentConverter();

        XStreamMarshaller xStreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        xStreamMarshaller.setAliases(aliases);
        xStreamMarshaller.setConverters(converter);

        xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().addPermission(NoTypePermission.NONE);
        xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().addPermission(NullPermission.NULL);
        xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().addPermission(PrimitiveTypePermission.PRIMITIVES);
        xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().allowTypeHierarchy(Collection.class);        
        xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().allowTypesByWildcard(new String[] {"com.example.demo.**"});        

        xmlFileReader.setUnmarshaller(xStreamMarshaller);


        SynchronizedItemStreamReader< StudentDTO> synchronizedItemStreamReader = new SynchronizedItemStreamReader<>();
        synchronizedItemStreamReader.setDelegate(xmlFileReader);
        return synchronizedItemStreamReader;
    }
```

I referenced some links but didn't get any significant idea how to approach the issue. Please give me some solution for my issue and some refernece to start with. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For my case there can be N number of records for student and the value of N can be really huge. My requirement is to parse the XML file and put the details of all the students into database and since i am using spring batch i don't want to load the whole XMl file at once. Due to large number of records i want to read the student data in batches let's say in a chunk size of 300.

This is how the [chunk-oriented processing model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#chunkOrientedProcessing) of Spring Batch works.

You need to configure a chunk-oriented step with a chunk size of 300. Spring Batch will read only 300 XML items in-memory at a time (and not the whole input file), process/write them before reading the next chunk.

You can find an example using the `StaxEventItemReader` in the [XML Input Output](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#xml-input-output) sample. The relevant section is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/iosample/xml.xml).

Comment: Sir, i have used StaxEventItemReader but it reads the whole XML at once including the header part which is of no use to me. I want to ignore the College part and just parse the student part in chunks using batch. I have asked an another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56704041 highlighting all the main details in detail. Please have a look and my apology for not mentioning all the points in detail

Comment: `but it reads the whole XML at once including the header part `: That does not mean the whole file will be read at once. You set the `FragmentRootElementName` to `student`, so only `student` tags will be read, other tags will be ignored by stax event reader.

Comment: Yeah i obseved that in the code. Thanks a lot for help