# How to parse only selected portion of XML using spring batch and convert it into java POJO

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to parse XML files and convert java POJO's from them. My Sample XML looks like

students.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<group>
    <college>
        <name>Hogwards</name>
        <city>Unknown</city>
    </college>
    <student>
        <name>Tony Tester</name>
        <rollNo>1</rollNo>
        <enrollmentDate>2016-10-31</enrollmentDate>
        <sampleTimeStamp>2016-11-07T05:50:45</sampleTimeStamp>
        <salary>16.57</salary>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Nick Newbie</name>
        <rollNo>2</rollNo>
        <enrollmentDate>2017-10-31</enrollmentDate>
        <sampleTimeStamp>2016-11-07T05:50:45</sampleTimeStamp>
        <salary>29.68</salary>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Ian Intermediate</name>
        <rollNo>3</rollNo>
        <enrollmentDate>2018-10-31</enrollmentDate>
        <sampleTimeStamp>2016-11-07T05:50:45</sampleTimeStamp>
        <salary>789.62</salary>
    </student>
</group>
```

Here, my goal is to parse the file and populate the student information into database using spring batch and for my purpose college information is kind of header for me which is totally useless and so in my batch reader i would like to ignore it and just i want to parse the student information in chunks. As of now my code is using GroupDTO class to parse the whole record at once and is creating at objects at a single time as a result of which i am unable to leveage the functionality of spring batch. My requirement says that student information should be parsed in chunks let's say in a chunk size of 300 or so. But as of now my code parses the whole XML files at one time and populate java objects from it. Please help me to ignore the college section part and just parse student section part in chunks using spring batch or suggest some appropriate link which may help me to find some solution for my issue. Thanks in advance...

XmlConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class XmlConfiguration 
{

    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @StepScope
    @Bean(name="xmlReader")
    public SynchronizedItemStreamReader<GroupDTO> reader() 
    {
        StaxEventItemReader<GroupDTO> xmlFileReader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
        xmlFileReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("students.xml"));
        xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("group");

        Map<String, Class<?>> aliases = new HashMap<>();
        aliases.put("group", GroupDTO.class);
        aliases.put("college", CollegeDTO.class);
        aliases.put("student", StudentDTO.class);

        XStreamMarshaller xStreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        xStreamMarshaller.setAliases(aliases);

        String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        String timeFormat = "HHmmss";
        String[] acceptableFormats = {timeFormat};

        xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().autodetectAnnotations(true);
        xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().registerConverter(new DateConverter(dateFormat, acceptableFormats));


        xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().addPermission(NoTypePermission.NONE);
        xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().addPermission(NullPermission.NULL);
        xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().addPermission(PrimitiveTypePermission.PRIMITIVES);
        xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().allowTypeHierarchy(Collection.class);
        xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().allowTypesByWildcard(new String[] {"com.example.demo.**"});

        xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().addImplicitCollection(GroupDTO.class, "list");          

        xmlFileReader.setUnmarshaller(xStreamMarshaller);      

        SynchronizedItemStreamReader<GroupDTO> synchronizedItemStreamReader = new SynchronizedItemStreamReader<>();
        synchronizedItemStreamReader.setDelegate(xmlFileReader);
        return synchronizedItemStreamReader;
    } 

    @Bean(name="xmlProcessor")
    public ItemProcessor<GroupDTO, GroupDTO> processor() 
    {
        return new Processor();
    }

    @Bean(name="xmlWriter")
    public ItemWriter<GroupDTO> writer() 
    {
        return new Writer();     
    }

    @Bean(name="xmljobListener")
    public JobExecutionListenerSupport jobListener() 
    {
        return new JobListener();
    }

    @JobScope
    @Bean(name="xmltaskExecutor")   
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() 
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(50);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean(name="xmlStep")
    public Step xmlFileToDatabaseStep() 
    {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("xmlStep")
                .<GroupDTO, GroupDTO>chunk(2)
                .reader(this.reader())
                .processor(this.processor())
                .writer(this.writer())
                .taskExecutor(this.taskExecutor())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name="xmlJob")
    public Job xmlFileToDatabaseJob(@Autowired @Qualifier("xmlStep") Step step) 
    {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("xmlJob"+new Date())
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(this.jobListener())
                .flow(step)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

}
```

GroupDTO.java

```
@XStreamAlias("group")
public class GroupDTO 
{
    @XStreamAlias("college")
    private CollegeDTO college;

    @XStreamAlias("student")
    private List<StudentDTO> list;

       ...... getter,setter, constructors
}
```

CollegeDTO.java

```
public class CollegeDTO 
{
    private String name;
    private String city;
        ...... getter,setter and constructor
}
```

StudentDTO.java

```
public class StudentDTO 
{
    private String name;
        private Integer rollNo;    
        private Date enrollmentDate;
        private Date sampleTimeStamp;
        private BigDecimal salary;
        ... getter, setter and constructor
}
```

Comment: Total noob in Spring Batch, here, but I'd say : set the fragment name to "student" (setFragmentRootElementName), and let it run (you may have to redefine your steps so that GroupDTO is replaced by StudentDTO). Given the name of the property, I'm pretty confident it tells the parser to consider each `student` as a separate `fragment`, so you'll get one per student. I'd look at it this way first.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, it worked as expected...

Answer (score 0):

Inside the job you have the tasklet that can use the chunk tag. It will has reader and writer properties and can it can has processor properties. The "processor" is optional.

```
   <batch:job id="helloWorldJob">
      <batch:step id="step1">
         <batch:tasklet>
             <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter"
                    processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="10">
             </batch:chunk>
         </batch:tasklet>
      </batch:step>
   </batch:job>
```

Then, when you declare the reader tag you will define the mapper.

```
<!--  READER -->
<bean id = "itemReader" 
    class = "org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">  
   ...
   <property name = "lineMapper"> 
      <bean class = "org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper"> 
          ...
          <property name = "fieldSetMapper"> 
             <bean class = "tudy.batch.Mapper" /> 
          </property> 
       </bean> 
    </property> 
 </bean>
```

This Mapper class is a great option to do what you want. This mapper will read the input file. What I imagine you need to do is just ignore the college tag.

```
public class Mapper implements FieldSetMapper<Student>{

    public Student mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {

        // Instantiating the report object
        Student student = new Student();

        // Setting the fields
        student.setName(fieldSet.readInt(0));
        student.setRollNo(fieldSet.readString(1));
        student.setEnrollmentDate(fieldSet.readString(2));
        student.setSampleTimeStamp(fieldSet.readString(3));
        student.setSalary(fieldSet.readString(4));

        return Student;
    }
}
```

You can use the index or the name. You should debug your code and confirm the position or the name how the college is coming to ignore that.